# SoundCloud API: what is the item limit on the activities feed?

Tags: soundcloud

As it's undocumented, what's the max limit I can reasonably set when using the activities feed?

I.e,

```
curl -i "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=200&oauth_token={}"
```

Will return a valid response.

But:

```
curl -i "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=1000&oauth_token={}"
```

Will return:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 07:22:50 GMT
Server: am/2
Content-Length: 26

{"error":"Unknown error."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default limit is 50, max is 200.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated

If you wanna page through all activities, you need to use the linked_partitioning parameter, described above.

or here under pagination:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was around 200!